# run-time error: '9' subscript out of range in Excel Macro 2016

Tags: vba, excel

I have a requirement to hide or un-hide certain tabs in an excel spreadsheet based on if a value is set to True or left blank on the cover page.

Using the code below in a macro it works until it reaches the last tab.

For example:  Tab 1 and 2 are set to True, Tab 3 and 4 are blank.

When the macro runs it will leave Tab 1 and 2 visible and hide tabs 3 and 4 but then it fails with the error

`run-time error '9' subscript out of range`.

I'm guessing that it is because there is nothing left for it to check so it fails.  How can I tell the macro to stop?  When I debug the code it highlights the line after the Else (Worksheets(cell.Value).Visible = xlSheetHidden)

```
If (Worksheets ("Cover").Cells(rValue, cell.Column).Value = True) Then
    Worksheets(cell.Value).Visible = xlSheetVisible
Else 
    Worksheets(cell.Value).Visible = xlSheetHidden 
End If
```

Comment: What is cell.Value when it fails? Is it an existing sheet in the appropriate workbook?

Comment: Hey @Chris It looks like we might not have enough information. What is cell? Is it a defined variables? Also It looks like Worksheets isn't fully qualified (but looks like cell.value is trying to do that, but without knowing what cell is its hard to say). And if cell isnt a variable, but indeed a cell, that isnt fully qualified either, which is why the compiler cant find it ergo "out of range" error.

Comment: You don't provide enough code. We don't see the logic of how you're getting the cell ranges, nor is it clear how the information is constructed.

Comment: Show us the entire loop.  It's likely you've gone one to far in setting the limit of your loop.  Several indexes start counting at 0 not 1.

Comment: I would also add that whatever youre using to scan through your "cover page" needs to be included as well. I am willing to bet youre not checking for blank or null cells in that range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here this achieves your goal.

```
Private Sub hideshit()
    Dim arr As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    arr = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange
    For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
        If arr(i, 2) = "n" Then
            Worksheets(i).Visible = False
        Else
            Worksheets(i).Visible = True
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Here's my test sample:

[image]

Comment: After some small modifications for my Worksheet that worked perfect.  Thanks

Comment: @Chris please mark as answered if this is sufficient